# Shortcomings of instrumenting compiled code before loading

Tags: java, classloader, instrumentation

Can anybody put lime light on what possible problems might emerge if an application created instruments class files before loading them using custom loader. I have created a java application that does the same thing.

I read class files in the form of byte arrays
Then I instrument using asm library and then
Load them through  custom class loader.

Is this procedure prone to failure if yes why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with this is that it ties your application to the JVM. The Java community works very hard on keeping the JLS and the JVMS separate, so that Java *could theoretically* be used without the JVM, and there are two fairly widespread platforms where Java *is actually* used without the JVM: Android and GWT. If you don't expect to ever need to run on a platform that doesn't understand Java byte code, then you are fine.

Note that *static* byte code manipulation stuff is perfectly okay. You can cross compile JVM byte code to Dalvik byte code *after* manipulating it. But if you wanted to do that at runtime, you would have to include the JVM-to-Dalvik cross compiler in your application … and it *still* wouldn't work because the Dalvik VM simply doesn't support dynamic byte code loading the same way the JVM does.